# Hausdorff dimension of subset of cartesian product

Tags: measure-theory

I am stuck on this question from Folland.

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has Hausdorff dimension $p$, then $A \times A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ has Hausdorff dimension $= 2p$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [$dim(A×A)\leq 2p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580978/hausdorff-dimension-of-cartesian-product/1682684)?

Comment: Yes this edition has this as errata

Comment: @Bullet51 I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the correct conclusion is $ \,  \dim(A \times A) \ge 2p$, while the reverse inequality only holds under additional assumptions (like equality of the Hausdorff and packing dimensions of $A$).

This is known as the Marstrand product theorem, generalized by Mattila. See, for example,  Theorem 3.2.1. in [1]  (page 89 in the linked PDF). You can also find it in the earlier books [2], [3].   (Theorem 3.2.1. in [1] assumes that $A$ is compact, but Theorem B.2.5. on page 352 there implies an extension to general Borel sets). The notes in [1], [2] and [3] include references to the original papers by Marstrand and Mattila.

Next, let's see that the upper bound of $2p$ on $\dim(A \times A)$ need not hold.
 Example 3.2.3. (page 90) in [1] gives two compact sets $A_S$ and $A_{S^c}$ in $[0,1]$, each of them of Hausdorff dimension zero, such that their Cartesian product has dimension 1. Then  $A:=A_s \cup A_{S^c}$
is a compact sets in the unit interval such that $\dim(A)=0$ yet $ \dim(A \times A) =1$.

[1] Bishop, Christopher J., and Yuval Peres. Fractals in probability and analysis. Vol. 162. Cambridge University Press, 2017.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fractals-in-probability-and-analysis/D8CBD4181FDC20C387E22939DA2F6168#fndtn-information

PDF available at at   https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math324.F15/book1Dec15.pdf

[2] Mattila, Pertti. Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean spaces: fractals and rectifiability. Vol. 44. Cambridge university press, 1999.

[3] KJ Falconer (1986). The geometry of fractal sets
Cambridge university press